# Multi User limited Time Encryption of big Datasets

Tags: encryption, protocol-design

### ***Updated Question: [New Thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57654/secure-big-data-files-from-theft)***

---

***Original Question:*** (Thanks cypherfox for answering that one)

I am in need to store data > 100 TB on a local network share (NAS/SAN) and grant individuals access to the encrypted data. For all users, besides me, the data can be read only, and sequential access to the data (only one user can access the data at one time) is fine.

The biggest problem is that I need to revoke individual users access from time to time (in addition to the recall of the network share access). I could encrypt the master key with user individual keys but this would not prevent technical experienced users from stealing the master key right? So I would need to re-encrypt the data every-time a user is recalled. Is there a way to do this more efficient than copying all data to a new encrypted image/disk? For 100 TB this would need more than 9 days.

Maybe someone can give me an advise which system/tools/techniques I should use and where the decryption should take place (client/server). Here the summarized key facts:

- ~ 100 TB Data
- max 5 user at the same time or 20 over the whole time span
- data stored an a local NAS/SAN connected to an 'offline' network
- the files have easily multiple GB, so some kind of transparent decryption to avoid copying the data would be necessary
- even a user could copy the data while he is a regular user, and even if he has no network share access anymore, we need to depreciate his decryption access

Comment: This kind of access control would be better managed with capabilities. Take a look at [Tahoe-LAFS](https://tahoe-lafs.org)

Comment: Although revocation is tricky in all cases. You cannot prevent someone from keeping a ciphertext (or plaintext) and its decryption key. But you can restrict the distribution of the ciphertext and revoke this authority to access the ciphertext than the ability to decrypt ciphertexts.

Comment: Makes sense. Looking a litte bit into Tahoe-LAFS it seems like the Data has to transfered via SFTP which is incredably slow. So downloading a single dataset of 50 GB would need more than one work shift. 
What do you think about giving people the ability to access the encrypted data (with their key), revoke their ability to access the network and remove them from the smb share (with encrypted transportation) as soon as their time is over. Furthermore I thinking of some kind of dedicated machine and offline network wherere logical datatheft would be quite hard to accomplish?

Comment: To clarify. I linked to Tahoe-LAFS because it divides keys for 3 roles: Read, Write, and Replicate/Store. You could attach another authority requirement to the replicate authority to restrict the distribution of ciphertexts such as an authority that you can add caveats and revoke: [Macaroons](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub41892.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by dividing the read, write, and replicate roles into 3 keys. [Tahoe-LAFS](https://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs) does this using "semiprivate" keys, each no larger than an EC curve point. I.e. Using ed25519, these keys would all be 32-bytes. The write key implies read, and the read key implies the replicate/verification key.

Once these keys have been revealed to someone, they cannot be revoked. To implement revocation, we need an additional authority that may be revoked, such as [Macaroons](https://research.google.com/pubs/pub41892.html). Macaroons support both delegation (sharing) and provisioning (with additional restrictions). These restrictions may reference clocks, or limit the functions the user may call (I.e. to read, write, append, truncate, delete, ..), or query out to external services to either check if the credential is still valid (revocation) or to check if the message is approved by the authority (configurable filters).

You cannot force a user to delete any ciphertexts, keys/credentials, nor plaintexts. You can revoke credentials to limit the distribution of ciphertexts. You don't need to rotate the encryption key so long that your adversary cannot also obtain the ciphertext (a revoked user cannot).

If your trusted server is allowed to read the user's data, then you don't need encryption at all (aside from session transports) as you only care about the authority to access. If the users can create new documents, then you'll likely prefer to lock the server (and you, the administrator) out of the user' personal data.

Comment: Sounds prmising at the moment but I have to digg a little bit deeper into your ideas as this is completly new to me.

Comment: More or less it is my data. No user needs the right to write, its not their data and all of them should be able to see the whole dataset. 
I trust the server as it is mine, but I need a least encyrtion on the server side in case the drives get stolen. But unfortunately this wont help against pysical attacks on the server ports (usb..).

Comment: Fair threat model. So you can skip the tahoe-lafs part and just use macaroons if you need the sharing. Otherwise if you have say SSH/SFTP, each user can just have an account that you can destroy ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! Yes, I can make my own server so indivudal accounts for sharing wouldn't be a problem (I will make a local network as well but I can not protect the ports). SSH/SFTP is unfortunately way to slow, thats the reason I wanted to use SMB3 with Encryption. Would it be sufficient to encrypt the data, decrypt it only on the client side (transparent image or so with encrypted network SM§ transportaion) to prevent data theft from physical attacks on the server?

Comment: How is ssh/sftp too slow? Is it because you need to work with many files? If so, then you can create an archive and fetch that, then extract it. I.e. `ssh user@server tar cJf - foo bar baz | tar xf -` to send the files/directories: foo, bar, and baz.

Comment: If you want to get partial updates as files change, then you can keep the tar archives and append the changes. IIUC tar will detect the changes and only append the actual changes. You can then send these incremental updates. Alternatively use `git`?

Comment: If the data doesn't compress well drop the `J` in the `tar` command. `git` also doesn't work well with large files.

Comment: The files are already one big binary (~50GB) and as I said the files wont get altered, so no need for git. The whole thing is basically for safe machine learning. The big data files will be parsed by the learning algorithm. Thats the reason why I would hate to download the file to the local filesystem, use it and then delte it. It would be way more efficient when a user could choose the file (network resource) and stream it (only chached in ram) to the learning algortihm.

I did some research, ssh is almost as fast as smb when dealing with big files. But as said, I want to avoid copying

Comment: Sounds like your question should be updated, or you should create another as this is straying far from the original question. ;-)

Comment: Or at least as I interpreted it

Comment: No I think you are right. I was thinking of one solution already and thus questioned in a wrong way. I will update the question if this is still possible.

Comment: I think you should revert it and ask a new question.

Comment: Or hmm.. I don't know :/

Comment: I'll take another look tomorrow. o/

Comment: No you were right. I reformulated the question and started a new thread as the question above was already answeread by you. Thanks again!